# Setting a breakpoint on a running Emacs Lisp program

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm having a problem with an Emacs lisp package that I pulled down from the ubuntu distribution.  The package is JDEE, and it complains of `Args out of range: "63", 0, 4` in the mini buffer and the `*Messages*` buffer whenever I open a file.  This bug appears to have been reported last September but no action has been taken.  I'm not an emacs newbie, having written some Elisp code myself, but I've never attempted to debug anything like this.  I would like to stop the file load in a debugger when this error happens to at least get an idea of where the problem is coming from.  I've read section 18.1.1 of the Elisp manual on "Entering the debugger on error" but trying to load the file after playing with various combinations of values for `debug-on-error`, `debug-ignored-errors`, and `debug-on-signal` appears to have no effect.  Has anybody got any suggestions for my next step?

Comment: Could you tell which Emacs version do you use, and how do you open a file (with command, keystroke or menubar item)?

Comment: I'm the one who reported this bug in Launchpad. Would you mind adding a "me too" over there, so maybe the maintainers will pay attention? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cedet/+bug/264498

Comment: Of course, submitting a patch would be fine too ;-)

Comment: slink: emacs is 22.1.1, and I open with find-file, which is bound to [C-x C-f]

Chris: added my report to yours.  Did you ever hear anything back on this?

Comment: Chris: I think I may have made a tiny bit of headway on this, do you perchance have '(jde-jdk (quote ("53"))) in the custom-set-variables of your .emacs?

Comment: I was unable to solve the problem of stopping the emacs lisp code to debug this, but I discovered the source of the issue while working on an unrelated problem.  It seems as if there is some issue with the debian initialization of JDE (which is also used in Ubuntu) which causes a wrong version to be used.  There is a workaround that fixed my problem here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=27174&sid=c1e6ef1f24c28bb5fabdfb23bdf6813b

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If debug-on-error isn't working, I'd start with the source itself.  Find the keybinding/event that is causing the problem, and locate the function.

```
C-h k <keystrokes>
M-x find-function <function-name-from-above>
```

Now, once you are at the source

```
M-x edebug-defun
```

And the next time you hit the key, you should be able to step through the program.  At that point, you can see which portion causes an error - and drill down that way.

You can also try setting the variable `'stack-trace-on-error` to see if you can find the culprit (though `'debug-on-error` usually works for me, not sure why it doesn't for you).

As a last resort (if `edebug-defun` doesn't work), you can redefine the routine with a call to `(debug)` in it, sort of does the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose JDEE is somehow inhibiting debug-on-error. Perhaps grep through its files for the error message "Args out of range". While debugging, make sure to load the uncompiled `.el` files, not the byte-compiled `.elc` files (you will notice it in the debugger if you are running byte-compiled code) by entering commands like `(load "foo.el")` instead of `(load "foo")`.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error when using `find-grep` after accidentally redefining `(current-time-string)` in one of my own scripts.

Using the `M-x edebug-defun` tip posted above I managed to find the issue when I stepped through the code giving the error seeing the call to `(current-time-string)`.

Not sure how helpful this is in your case.

Comment: -1 "Args out of range" is a pretty generic error. Plus the question is how to start the debugger not what caused the error.